# App Crashing with EXC_BREAKPOINT Error

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I have an app I am making in Xcode 7.2. I have a main menu with a button that has a segue going to a settings view controller. The settings view controller has the following code and every time I get to that view controller it crashes with an EXC_BREAKPOINT error. The funny thing is that this only happens on my iPhone 4 running iOS 7. It does not crash in the iOS Simulator iPhone 6 running iOS 9.

Anyways, here is the code.

```
//
//  SettingsController.swift
//  Arbor Hills iOS
//
//  Created by Andrew on 11/22/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Arbor Hills Vet. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class SettingsController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var username: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var notifications: UISwitch!
    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        let dusername = defaults.valueForKey("username")!

        let dpassword = defaults.valueForKey("password")!
        let dnotifications = defaults.valueForKey("notifications")!

        username!.text = String(dusername)
        password!.text = String(dpassword)
        if(dnotifications as! Bool == true){
            notifications.setOn(true, animated: true)
        }else{
            notifications.setOn(false, animated:true)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func saveUsername(sender: AnyObject) {
       let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        defaults.setObject(username.text!, forKey: "username")
    }

    @IBAction func savePassword(sender: AnyObject) {
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        defaults.setObject(password.text!, forKey: "password")
    }

    @IBAction func notificationsModified(sender: AnyObject) {
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        defaults.setObject(notifications.on, forKey: "notifications")
    }

    }
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint in viewDidLoad and debug one by one line in this from iphone4s ios 7 and let us know where it crash.

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari It crashed after this line: let dusername = defaults.valueForKey("username")!

Comment: it means that the username key data is not present. Make a nil check there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults` returns `nil` for an object if no default value is registered. When you unwrap a `nil` value you'll get an runtime error (crash).

Apple recommends to register a default value for any key as a placeholder until a custom value is saved the first time.

In `AppDelegate` add in `applicationDidFinshLaunching`

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let defaultValues = ["username" : "", "password" : "", "notifications" : false]
defaults.registerDefaults(defaultValues)
```

**Swift 3+**

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
let defaultValues : [String : Any] = ["username" : "", "password" : "", "notifications" : false]
userDefaults.register(defaults: defaultValues)
```

That registers empty strings and a boolean `false`.
Then you can safely retrieve the values

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let dusername = defaults.stringForKey("username")!
let dpassword = defaults.stringForKey("password")!
let dnotifications = defaults.boolForKey("notifications")
```

**Swift 3+**

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
let dusername = defaults.string(forKey:"username")!
let dpassword = defaults.string(forKey:"password")!
let dnotifications = defaults.bool(forKey:"notifications")
```

Use always `stringForKey` for `String` values and `boolForKey` for `Bool` values.
**Never** use `valueForKey` with `NSUserDefaults` which is a special KVC method.

Then this code could be also simplified:

```
username!.text = dusername
password!.text = dpassword
notifications.setOn(dnotifications, animated: true)
```

When writing to user defaults use `setBool:forKey` for the `Bool` value, however there is no `String` equivalent, `setObject:forKey` is correct.

Comment: Thank you.  This helped a lot. I guess I was unaware of the registerDefaults method.

Comment: Unfortunately most people are unaware of registering default values although it's described in depth in the documentation and available since Mac OS 10.0

Comment: I see now that you fixed the OP's misuse of valueForKey as well as registering a "default default" value. (Voted). The only think I would change in your code is not force-unwrapping the optional, but using `if let`. In this case it will work because of registering the default, but it's not a good habit to get into with user defaults because it will crash if the default value doesn't exist.

Comment: The main purpose of registering default values is that you have **always** 100% safe non-optional values. Optional binding is not needed at all. When you launch the application the first time, you have 2 strings and one boolean and they are never nil.

Comment: Registering default values is very helpful. I always put my call to `registerDefaultValues` in the app delegate's initialize() call, which gets invoked before the app delegate is even instantiated. That way you can safely assume that your "default default" values are defined in **ALL(( of your application code.

Comment: Apple writes: *You can register default values at any time, of course, but should always register them before attempting to retrieve any preference values.*

Answer (score 0):

You should not use valueForKey to fetch objects from NSUserDefaults. Thats a key-value coding method. (See the link on [**NSKeyValueCoding**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/). you want objectForKey, and you need to check for nil afterwords:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
if let dusername = defaults.objectForKey("username") as String
{
  //code to use the username
}
else
{
  //code to handle the case where there is no username
}
```

Comment: No, he should be using `stringForKey`, not `objectForKey`. See my answer ;-)

Comment: Either is valid, and yes, I agree that using stringForKey is cleaner. My point is that the code in the question cannot work.

Comment: I know, I was kidding quoting your comment almost literally. Nevertheless registering  default values is the recommended way.

Comment: @vadian register values is I guess just the same as initializing the key values.

Comment: @vadian Also do registerDefaults runs only if the key val is nil or everytime it makes a default value for the respective key?

Comment: `registerDefaults` is supposed to run every time to make sure there is a default value in case the preference file has been deleted. That ensures that the value can't be `nil`

Comment: `registerDefaults` creates a value that is used if you have never added an object for a specific key. It creates a "default default". The first time you save a value for that key, it overrides the value you specified in `registerDefaults`. As @vadian says, it is well documented. You should go read about it.

Comment: hmm. Got it. Thanks @vadian for `registerDefaults`.  Just like the author I too haven't used before.